# observable collection static resource in xaml c#

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create an observable collection and bind it to itemsource of a combobox dropdown. I need to make this collection a resource (page/grid) to be able to bind to it inside a data template.
Need help in defining a class  structure . A sample class structure will really help. Collection is very simple, e.g. a list of all countries. Important requirement is that i should be able to add items to it.
Basically a collection containing countries (string) that allows me to add items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> observable collection static resource in xaml c#

For this requirement, you could make custom [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) class  in the code-behind, then implement it in the xaml.

For example:

```
public class CountrysObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<string>
{

    public CountrysObservableCollection()
    {

    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:CountrysObservableCollection x:Key="Countrys">
        <x:String>China</x:String>
        <x:String>USA</x:String>
        <x:String>Japan</x:String>
        <x:String>England</x:String>
        <x:String>Russia</x:String>
        <x:String>Korea</x:String>
        <x:String>Canada</x:String>
        <x:String>Australia</x:String>
    </local:CountrysObservableCollection>
</Page.Resources>
```

**Usage**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Countrys}"/>
```

Update DataSource

```
private  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var countrys = Resources["Countrys"] as ObservableCollection<string>;
    countrys.Add("New World");
}
```

**update**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:CountrysObservableCollection x:Key="Countrys">
            <x:String>China</x:String>
            <x:String>USA</x:String>
            <x:String>Japan</x:String>
            <x:String>England</x:String>
            <x:String>Russia</x:String>
            <x:String>Korea</x:String>
            <x:String>Canada</x:String>
            <x:String>Australia</x:String>
        </local:CountrysObservableCollection>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>



 private  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var countrys = Application.Current.Resources["Countrys"]as ObservableCollection<string>;  
     countrys.Add("New World");
 }
```

Comment: can you please tell me syntax to add items to this class from c# After the combobox is initialized. e.g. when user adds another country

Comment: Sure, You could get this collection with `var countrys = Resources["Countrys"] as ObservableCollection<string>;` in the page class.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I tried it and it seems to be working except one last bit. I need click button on one page and country update on another page (separate window). So, is there a way i can declare observable collection as application resource instead of page resource so all pages have access to it? i am looking for a way to allow one page to add countries and second page to be able to see the changes

Comment: Sure, you could place above in the app's application resource

Comment: I am getting following error: A value of type CountrysObservableCollection cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'1''

Comment: i cannot add this resource to app.xaml. I am getting following error: I am getting following error: A value of type CountrysObservableCollection cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'1'

Comment: I have upload code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/XamlArrayTest). please check that.

Comment: It turns out you don't need to specify the constructor for `CountrysObservableCollection`

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of examples on the web. Here is a simple one: [Explain Combo Box Binding In MVVM - WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/)

Comment: i cannot find a UWP example. can you share one? what type of class do i need? what should i search on google?

Comment: i tried the Persons example and i can display the comboBox. However, how can i add more items dynamically in my code. e.g. if i want to allow user to add new Person.