# System.ObjectModel assembly is giving issues on Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having an issue while using observable collection in XAML. I have created tabs on my Xamarin.Forms application using observable collection in XAML and for accessing observable collection in XAML I have included this namespace

***xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System.ObjectModel"***

when I am writing System.ObjectModel in assembly it is working fine in iOS and UWP but crashing on Android. If I am writing netstandard assembly instead of System.ObjectModel then it is working fine in Android but crashing in iOS and UWP.

I have tried installing System.ObjectModel package in my project but it didn't work.

My XAML looks something like this

```
         <ResourceDictionary>

            <!--  Default list  -->
            <xcoll:ObservableCollection x:Key="NewTabs" x:TypeArguments="model:ISequenceItem">
                <test:FirstPage Order="1" Text="Page 1" />
                <test:SecondPage Order="2" Text="Page2" />
                <test:ThirdPage Order="3" Text="Page3" />
            </xcoll:ObservableCollection>

         </ResourceDictionary>

        <test:Tabs
        ItemSource="{Binding Path=NewTabs}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTab}">
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen anyone use an ObservableCollection in xaml. Its typically used in a viewmodel, as an itemsSource for a CollectionView, ListView, or layout using BindableLayout. A collection of models, not of views. Explain more about what you are doing. And why you think ObservableCollection is needed. If you've seen this usage somewhere, please provide a link.

Comment: I had searched this on the internet and found that use the ObservableCollection in the xaml always in the WPF, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63820481/observable-collection-static-resource-in-xaml-c-sharp).